# ¿Cómo crear un diccionario con una regex sabiendo que texto extraer, pero no si aparece en una entrada dada?

Tags: python, regex

estoy tratando de extraer datos de una porción de html que puede variar la información que tiene en un listado.

A continuación las posbiles porciones de html con sus respectiva salida esperada.

#### Ejemplo 1

```html
<ul>
    <li class="contentnode">
        <dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl>
    </li>
    <li class="contentnode">
        <dl><dt>Ciudad</dt><dd>Foo</dd></dl>
    </li>
    <li class="contentnode">
        <dl><dt>Email</dt><dd>123@gail.com</dd></dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Salida esperada:

```py
{'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo', 'email': '123@gail.com'}
```

#### Ejemplo 2

```html
<ul>
    <li class="contentnode">
        <dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl>
    </li>
    <li class="contentnode">
        <dl><dt>Ciudad</dt><dd>Foo</dd></dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Salida esperada:

```py
{'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo', 'email': None}
# o también
{'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo'}
```

#### Ejemplo 3

```html
<ul>
    <li class="contentnode">
        <dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Salida esperada:

```py
{'country': 'Uganda', 'city': None, 'email': None}
# o también
{'country': 'Uganda'}
```

#### Ejemplo 4

```html
<ul>
    <li class="contentnode">
        <dl><dt>Email</dt><dd>123@gail.com</dd></dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Salida esperada:

```py
{'country': None, 'city': None, 'email': '123@gail.com'}
# o también
{'email': '123@gail.com'}
```

### Detalles

- Se puedo saber que campos se van a extraer los datos pero no si los campos están.
- El diccionario debe ser creado en un solo paso y de forma completa debido a razones que no vienen al caso, es decir, no se debe hacer (en lo posible) una verificación previa de si *algo* está o no para luego extraer el dato y agregarselo al diccionario.
- La tarea se debe concentrar en lo posible en la expresión regular.
- La entrada (html) que recibe la expresión regular no tiene saltos de línea. Ejemplo:

```html
<ul><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl></li><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Ciudad</dt><dd>Foo</dd></dl></li><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Email</dt><dd>123@gail.com</dd></dl></li></ul>
```

### Intento

Hé probado con la siguiente expresión regular:

```py
import re
# input
html = '<ul><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl></li><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Ciudad</dt><dd>Foo</dd></dl></li><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Email</dt><dd>123@gail.com</dd></dl></li></ul>'
# regex
pattern = r'<dt>(?:País</dt><dd>(?P<country>\w+)|Ciudad</dt><dd>(?P<city>\w+)|Email</dt><dd>(?P<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+))</dd>'
m = re.search(pattern, html)
print(m.groupdict())
```

```py
mi salida:       {'country': 'Uganda', 'city': None, 'email': None}
salida esperada: {'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo', 'email': '123@gail.com'}
```

Desde ya gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si asumimos que tu html tiene las tres etiquetas `li` siempre en ese orden, puedes combinar grupos de no captura (`?:`) que envuelva a cada `li` con el cuantificador `?` (cero o uno) para hacerlos opcionales:

```
import re


html1 = '<ul><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl></li><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Ciudad</dt><dd>Foo</dd></dl></li><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Email</dt><dd>123@gail.com</dd></dl></li></ul>'
html2 = '<ul><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl></li><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Ciudad</dt><dd>Foo</dd></dl></li></ul>'
html3 = '<ul><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>País</dt><dd>Uganda</dd></dl></li></ul>'
html4 = '<ul><li class="contentnode"><dl><dt>Email</dt><dd>123@gail.com</dd></dl></li></ul>'


pattern = re.compile(r'''
<ul>
    (?:<li\ class=\"contentnode\">
        <dl>
            <dt>País</dt>
            <dd>(?P<country>\w+)</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>)?.*?
    (?:<li\ class=\"contentnode\">
        <dl>
            <dt>Ciudad</dt>
            <dd>(?P<city>\w+)</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>)?.*?
    (?:<li\ class=\"contentnode\">
        <dl>
            <dt>Email</dt>
            <dd>(?P<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>)?
</ul>''', flags=re.VERBOSE)


for html in (html1, html2, html3, html4):
    m = pattern.search(html)
    print(m.groupdict())
```

> ```
> {'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo', 'email': '123@gail.com'}
> {'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo', 'email': None}
> {'country': 'Uganda', 'city': None, 'email': None}
> {'country': None, 'city': None, 'email': '123@gail.com'}
> ```

Si quieres no incluir los valores `None` puedes filtrar el diccionario:

```
for html in (html1, html2, html3, html4):
    m = pattern.search(html)
    print({group: value for group, value in m.groupdict().items() if value is not None})
```

> ```
> {'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo', 'email': '123@gail.com'}
> {'country': 'Uganda', 'city': 'Foo'}
> {'country': 'Uganda'}
> {'email': '123@gail.com'}
> ```

Normalmente no es buena idea usar regexs para parsear html/xml, pero supongo que tendrás tus razones para usar expresiones regulares en vez de usar un parser específico.

Comment: ¿qué sugieres para parsear el html? Estoy con la libreria `MechanicalSoup`, he buscado en la documentación de `MechanicalSoup` y de `BeautifulSoup` pero no encontré nada parecido para realizar esta tarea.